# can't click on an element due to google ads

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I've been trying to do automation using selenium and need to click on links but the webpage has google ads which is not letting me click on the buttons. How do I overcome this problem?

this is the code

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Illinois')
elem.click()
```

and this is the error

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/state/IL">...</a> is not clickable at point (497, 858). Other element would receive the click: <iframe frameborder="0" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-37/html/container.html?2ad90d8b823cd41d3186f3484dae4192" id="google_ads_iframe_/1254144/netronline_com-medrectangle-2_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="970" height="90" data-is-safeframe="true" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" data-google-container-id="12" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" data-load-complete="true"></iframe>
```

I tried webdriver too but getting timeout error

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@href='https://Link.com' and contains(.,'Illinois')]"))).click()
```

Comment: Please post your html or share url if this pulic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
linkText= WebDriverWait(browser, 20 ).until( 
EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.LINK_TEXT, "Illinois") ) )
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", linkText)
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: it says self is not defined

Comment: What is not defined ?

Comment: I removed the self and it worked, however in the next page, I again got the timeout error

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to handle on the next page, I think you can use webdriver wait to handle synchronization issue , if you already used wait  then you can check if element is within iframe.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to accept my answer from your end